# How to print the name of a variable passed to a function in C?

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define getName(var)  #var

struct books
{
  char title[100];
  char author[100];
  char subject[100];
  int bookid;
};

void printbooks(struct books book)
{
   printf("The title of %s %s\n",getName(book),book.title);
   printf("%s\n",book.author);
   printf("%s\n",book.subject);
   printf("%d\n",book.bookid);
}

struct books book1;

int main()
{

   strcpy(book1.title,"A tale of two cities");
   strcpy(book1.author,"Charles Dickens");
   strcpy(book1.subject,"Romance");
   book1.bookid = 1000;

   printbooks(book1);
}
```

The reason why I introduced the `#define getName(var) #var` macro is to print the output the following way:

```
The title of book1 is A tale of two cities
```

Obviously this does not work. Is there a way to do this?

PS: I came across this completely accidentally and in fact there seems to be no real need for something like this. But still I wanted to know if it is possible or not is all.

Comment: C doesn't have [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_(computer_science)). It's really impossible to do what you want without storing the variable name itself in the code as a string.

Comment: This is not needed in C, why do you need such feature ?

Comment: @Stargateur: As you can see in the above case if I pass book1 then it would be better if it prints "the title of book1 is A tale of two cities" and say if I pass another book2 then it would be better if it prints say "the title of book2 is A brief history of time".

Comment: That answer what you want but not why.

Comment: This can't be done in `c`.. you'll need to completely rethink your approach, which may include using a different language. To do something like this in `c`, I would populate an array of `struct books`, then use either an index in that array or the `bookid` to print out the identifier for the book.

Comment: Suppose you have `struct books books[200];` and you pass `books[(147 * i +j) % 200]` to `printbook()` — what do you expect `getName()` to return?  Don't forget, the value in the function is a copy of the value passed to the function.

Comment: Variable names exists for the _programmer_ and the programmer only. Not for the user. If your users need to know your variable names, you are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? Why do you want to know the name of the variable? What is the use case? If it's for debugging, you'd better use a debugger.

Comment: This would be considered a bad idea even in languages that do support introspection.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`  to expose the prototype for the function: `strcpy()`  While the header file: `strings.h` (note the plural) exists, it is not for this purpose.

Comment: why pass the `struct book` parameter to the function: `printBooks()`?  Since the instance of `struct book` is a file global data item.  Of course, it is 'usually' a bad idea to make data 'file global'.  Suggest placing the instance of `struct book` as a local variable inside the `main()` function

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach by using macro:

```
#define PRINT_BOOK(_book_variable) \
    printf("The title of " #_book_variable " is %s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", \
        _book_variable.title, \
        _book_variable.author, \
        _book_variable.subject, \
        _book_variable.bookid)

int main(void)
{
    struct books book1 = {.title="A tale of two cities", 
                          .author="Charles Dickens", 
                          .subject="Romance", 
                          .bookid=1000};
    PRINT_BOOK(book1);
}
```

Note that usage will be different from your original approach. 
A macro is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for assuming that you do not really want the variable name some which piece of code uses to identify a piece of memory with the data on a book.

I propose to achieve the desired output (which I assume to be a meaningful attribute of the meta information stored on any given book not of any C construct handling it) by this code:

```
printf("The title of the book with ID %d is: %s\n", book1.bookid, book1.title);
```

You might alternatively be handling a special set of books and each has a certain semantic. E.g. comparing the release date of two seelcted books (introducing another member of your struct, an integer epoch, for demonstration purposes):

```
if(book1.date>book2.date) 
{
    printf("The first selected book is younger than the second selected book.\n");
} else if(book1.date<book2.date) 
{
    printf("The first selected book is older than the second selected book.\n");
} else
{
    printf("The two books were published at the same time.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share what is the output you got with the code?

I tried the code and here is what I got:

`The title of book A tale of two cities`

which is exactly what I would expect. Since you are invoking the macro from `printbooks()` function, it will print the local variable name which is `book`.

If you want to print `book1`, you need to invoke the macro from `main()`. Here is my output when I invoke the macro from `main()`.

`The title of book1 A tale of two cities`

p.s. "is" is missing in the code.